# Prototype, Dojo and Scriptaculous together

Tags: javascript, dojo, prototypejs, scriptaculous

Can these three frameworks work together? And if so, which requirements must be fulfilled?

Answer (score 2):

Dojo has the advantage of working with any other library because everything is in the Dojo namespace. Scriptacolus requires prototype so there is no problem there. Just make sure you don't try to use jQuery with prototype as they will conflict with each other.